# How to design table to allow marking records as related to each other?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key, primary-key

My web app's main MySQL table has tens of thousands of rows. Pretend it has 2 columns: ID, Content.

I'm trying to design a new feature that allows rows to be marked as related to each other.

Obviously I could add a 3rd column: Related_IDs. It could either be a JSON array or could be a simple CSV string.

But that feels wrong. I'd need to update the Related_IDs field of each row of a group of N rows to be a comma-separated list of IDs of all of the rows in the group except itself. Every time any one of those records becomes unrelated, I'd need to iterate through the group and clean up that field for each.

What is a smarter approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bridge table

```
related_id  Related_TO_ID
     13           2
     13          12
```

If `1-->2  is equal to 2-->1` you need one row else you need two.

Now You can get all ids that are related to 13

And if you want to exclude some ration ships you can add a column that indicates that 13 is never related to 42

```
SELECT Related_TO_ID FROM brdgetable WHERE related_id   = 13
```

Why you never should save data in delimitedcolumns you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Thanks very much for the link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad. As for the joiner table, that was the only other approach I was thinking of, but it still feels odd because if 6 rows are related to each other, I'd either need to have 6*5 = 30 rows [ie. N*(N-1)] about the relationships OR if I code my app in a way that also checks the relationship from the other side (as you implied), I'd still need (5+4+3+2+1 = 15) rows to map the relationships [ie. N-1 + N-2 + N -3...].

Comment: I guess an alternative would be to have a `PostGroups` table with just 1 column: ID.

A new `PostGroups` row would automatically get created as soon as a user wanted to mark any `Posts` rows as related to each other. Then the one-to-many `PostGroupsPosts` joiner table would have columns group_id and post_id. I could set post_id as unique since I only want a post to be able to be a member of one group.

So then a group of related posts would just be N rows in the `PostGroupsPosts` table.

Comment: no such bridge tables are only integer values and when indexed with a combined index this is very fast, and i doubt that the worst  case it gets factorial , that would mean everything is related to every thing, but if a post is only relqated to one group, you don't need a bridge table ,because that is anly for n to m relationships. In your case a simple id to a group table is enough